# Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 mido userdata partition type / data recovery

Tags: data-recovery, linux, xiaomi, broken-screen, loopback

I am doing data recovery on a Xaomi Redmi Note 4(x?) [mido] and I have finally gotten a flash dump ( the screen is scuffed and no perms have been set ( no adb,oem unlock, storage access ))
Only way to recover the data would've been to dump the userdata, loopback mount it and copy the files. simple enough, done a few.

except no. the tool I used to get the partition table and flash dump says

```
userdata: Offset 0x0000000148082000, Length 0x0000000d47779e00, Flags 0x0000000000000000, UUID 0f772dd9-b55d-1184-ecf9-bb352eb97272, Type 0x1b81e7e6, Active False
```

The 'Type' part is what confuses me most, it's twice as long to be a gdisk partition-id-thing and far too short to be a GUID
This wouldn't matter if I could mount it to begin with, but thing is, binwalk reports that at offset 0xDCDB29 there is a 'VMware4 disk image'.

I try to mount this via qemu-nbd but no ext filesystem ( or others for that matter ) is found

does the mido do FDE even without a passcode? the phone doesn't have one I forgot to mention...

And if that's the case, how do I even decrypt the data?
I've asked on a couple other forums for help already, nothing yet.

Honestly any method / guide to broken screen recovery on a full stock android is much apreciated!

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4061651

Comment: The phone was shipped with Android 6, so encryption would be a possible cause but the number of devices that come pre-encrypted was as far as I remember not very high. Do you see readable plain text when looking at the hex dump of the partition? If you see plain text then it might be a different file-system like F2FS.

Comment: security concern my cheeks, there's no pin/pass code/word to unlock it! never was either!!
thanks for the link @alecxs 
no readable strings were found, besides I expect jpg png or similar files with binwalk I'm told there's a lotof those, the bit magic is all over the place with VDIs and Adobe Flash uncompressed data

Comment: kinda figured the bootloader part, from what I gather the keys change when bootloader is unlocked, I could also tell by hexdump rather quickly that it was encrypted.

Comment: exploit was discovered by [xaacnz](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3772381) on Redmi 5a, untested on Redmi 4. have you seen [twrp-hack.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-unlock-xiaomi-redmi-note-4-without-wiping-data.4061651/post-81948657) post #19 - you could try same for your current ROM. use edl.py from linux, no need to hassle with QPST rawprogram0.xml offsets